# Fundamental solution of heat equation on a compact Riemannian manifold

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold of $m$ dimensional. 
Then there exists a sequence $(\phi_i, \lambda_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subset C^\infty(M)\times\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ such that 
\begin{eqnarray}
0=\lambda_0<\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\cdots\to\infty\\
\Delta\phi_i+\lambda_i\phi_i=0\\
\end{eqnarray}
and $(\phi_i)_i$ forms a complete orthonormal system of $L^2(M)$.

Then, my textbook says that
\begin{equation}
H(x,y,t):=\sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda_it}\phi_i(x)\phi_i(y)
\end{equation}
is the fundamental solution of the heat equation $\Delta u-\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$.

I cannot understand what the sum means. Does the sum converge in $L^2(M\times M)$ for all $t$? Or does it converge pointwise on $M\times M\times (0,\infty)$? I want to know the mean of the $H$ as a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It converges uniformly in $M\times M$ for each $t>0$. If I remember correctly, a proof is given in Rosenberg's *Laplacian on Riemannian manifolds*. Chavel's book must also have something on this. In any case the proof is straightforward if you use Weyl's law (Please try).