# Heat Kernel on a compact manifold without boundary

Tags: probability, manifolds, heat-equation, regularization

I was wondering if the conservation of mass which is obvious for the heat equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ holds also for the heat kernel in a general compact manifold without boundary.

I mean I want to know if the heat kernel generally satisfies

$$\int dx K(x,y,t)=1$$

If so, may I have some references to look at?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very cool question. Some related questions about the heat kernel on compact manifolds:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2374862/532409 ,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3268595/532409 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3881917/532409 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/984254/532409 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2700522/532409 , MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/331870/333546 . Regarding the "the conservation of mass" (on the torus): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3759470/532409

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's true, and is easy to prove in this setting.  Differentiate under the integral sign to get
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int K(x,y,t)\,dx = \int \partial_t K(x,y,t)\,dx = \int \Delta K(x,y,t)\,dx$$
the Laplacian $\Delta$ taken in the $y$ variable.  Now integrating by parts,
$$\int \Delta K(x,y,t)\,dx = \int K(x,y,t) \Delta 1\,dx = 0$$
so that $\int K(x,y,t)\,dx$ is constant with respect to $t$.

To show it's a constant with respect to $y$, you could again differentiate under the integral sign to show that $F(y,t) = \int K(x,y,t)\,dx$ also solves the heat equation, and since it's independent of $t$, it is harmonic.  The only continuous harmonic functions on a compact manifold without boundary are constants, by the maximum principle.

More generally, any Riemannian manifold for which this holds is said to be *stochastically complete*.  It's well known (but not quite so easy to prove) that every complete Riemannian manifold with Ricci curvature bounded below is stochastically complete; see for instance

> *Hsu, Pei*, [**Heat semigroup on a complete Riemannian manifold**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/aop/1176991267), Ann. Probab. 17, No. 3, 1248-1254 (1989). [ZBL0694.58043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0694.58043).

and references therein.

Comment: Thank you very much! And can I say something about other $L^p$ norms as well?

Comment: @Bric: What do you want to say?

Comment: Sorry it's not a precise question. I was wondering for example  if there's an estimate for the $L^p$ norm like in the $R^n$ case. Actually the thing I  really need  is if I can have an estimate on $\sup_t|u(x,t)|=\int dy K(x,y,t)u_0(y)$ only having $u_0\in L^1$

Comment: I don't have the results off the top of my head, but a good place to look is the book *Heat kernels and spectral theory* by E.B. Davies.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look to the book you suggested and it is really good but I solved my doubt in another way ;) Anyway thanks again